# Tools to help automate/speed up creating CRUD web apps?

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications, flash-builder

I'm taking a user interface design course this semester, and so the emphasis is on the actual UI, not on the behind-the-scenes application code.  The prof has said we don't need to create real, completely functional apps, but since the app will really just involve simple CRUD transactions, I would prefer to make something that actually works.  I'd like to do a web app with the presentation layer done in Flex (Flash Builder's design view seems easier to work with than NetBeans', which is what the prof showed us in class, plus the job I just started last month uses Flex, so it'll help with work, too).

Anyway I recently came across [RestfulX](http://restfulx.github.com/), and in googling I discovered [Jspresso](http://www.jspresso.org/), and both of these seem like really nice tools to help automate creating the application and data access layers.  I'd like to learn about other similar tools, but I'm not even sure what they're called in order to search for them.

Can anybody point me to more of these tools that would work for me (assuming more are out there)?  My requirements are fairly simple: I want it to work with Flex 4.5 or 4.6, I'd like to use a serverless database such as HSQLDB or SQLite, and everything needs to be able to be run without admin privileges on Linux (so I can run the app on the school's servers).  If you know of a tool that would fit the bill, I'd really appreciate the info.

Comment: You might consider looking into Node.JS and then perhaps AngularJS for the front-end. Node works with sqlite and every other database you can think of. If you can install Mongo, then there's a neat node module called "Mongoose" that does all your crud stuff for you.

Comment: @JonathanRowny not to be a troll but isn't that kind of like saying well if you like boats you're going to love planes, or so you say you need to use a jack hammer, well this screwdriver and hammer should work great for you :)  Not to knock Node or anything but it's just a completely different beast.

Comment: @JonathanRowny I have to take back my statement to some degree.  He could consider using Node.js on the server side, I was just immediately thinking about the whole niceness of writing javascript on both sides which would negate the use of Flex for the front-end.  However as you suggest this is a viable alternative for the server side.  Node allows you to easily bind to a port and create response handlers that can be run "server side".  Up-voted you to redeem myself.

Comment: @JonathanRowny Perhaps I'm missing something, but would node.js help with the code generation type of thing (e.g. [RestfulX's code generation feature](https://github.com/dima/restfulx/wiki/Getting-started-with-RestfulX-and-Ruby-On-Rails) ) That's really the part I'm most interested in; I've got a limited amount of time to create this app, so I want to put in as little work as possible on the not-required application and data layers as I can.

Comment: @shaunhusain Since Flex can now natively consume JSON (and before that using common libraires), Node.JS becomes a good backend for ANY client. It only serves what you need it to serve and and nothing else. And, yes, I was hoping to inspire a little bit of plane loving for those people stuck on boats. I only mentioned Angular because it has some nice similarities with Flex.

Comment: @Maltiriel well, an ORM does CRUD. You describe your model... `{someProperty:{type:"String", default:"Yay"}}` and then you can say `instance.save()` and you're done. With Node.JS you've got many choices. There would still be some work involved, but not too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebORB works pretty well, you can also use the built in code generation in Flex/Flash Builder (it doesn't create pretty code but it's functional), using the services you give it a DB connection and it spits back service and client DTO objects and CRUD services (in the form of PHP or Java classes). http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_4.html I assume you can run XAMPP to prop up the PHP and MySQL backend.  Basically when you go to create a new project you can select a server type then from there you would use the services panel in Flex, right click and create a new service, it will ask what the DB source is you give it that connection information and it gives you a list of tables, you select a table and it creates a DTO for both sides and a service file that has CRUD written up for you.  You can then also easily drag and drop those services onto Flex components to bind to the result of a service call.

Another alternative is to use AIR if a web app isn't a requirement and a full on desktop app would be acceptable.  In that case you'd be able to start up a native process in the background that can be written in whatever you fancy to establish the connection to the DB and act as a proxy to pass data back to the AIR front-end (with a native process you get a pipe to the standard input/output/error that you can use as a channel to pass data back and forth).  In this scenario you would write the "connector" in say Java or some other language that has a simple means to obtain a connection to a DB and execute queries with results, in that layer you'd want to format the data in some way that makes it easy for the client code to interpret... XML is probably the easiest way then you can use E4X in the client code to parse out what you need for display or storage in a model.

Comment: From the looks of it, XAMPP seems to be only for Windows.  If that's the case it's not really helpful: I want to run this on the department's Linux servers.  While it's not required to be a web app, it seems like the easiest course to me, because I wouldn't have to bring my laptop in any time the prof wants a demo, and I can send the link to friends to ask them to try it out, stuff like that.

I'll take a look at the built in Flash Builder stuff though; I had no idea it was there (I'm new to Flex/Flash as of getting this job).  And I'll look at WebORB. Thanks.

Comment: @Maltiriel there's LAMP for Linux I thought XAMPP was cross platform though, all of those are just Apache MySQL and PHP packaged up together so you don't have to really configure anything, the only thing I would question is if you can run that without being root.  To note it's an insecure configuration but it's good for things like this where security isn't really a concern.  That would give you the service layer platform (PHP) and DB (MySQL) in one shot though.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. I know I can run Apache, and other people in the department have done MySQL I'm pretty sure, so I would think it would work...  I'll look into it.  I'm liking the looks of WebORB so far, btw.  The mobile app integration features seem very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

jspresso looks nice. For a fast and working prototype, you can use Flash Builder code generation in PHP. PHP can run on Windows/Linux/Mac and there are different setups available e.g. XAMPP, WAMP and LAMP.